# Default index shard allocation

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to understand Elasticsearch default rules for shard allocation. I have 6 nodes and created a test index with all default settings (5 shards, 1 replica). To my surprise, all 5 primary shards are collocated in a single node (the node to which the creation request was sent -- not sure if this is coincidence) while replicas are spread around. I realize this configuration is contrived, but I would appreciate any help in understanding why the primary shards are not being scattered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of elasticsearch ? Also are there any "cluster.routing.allocation.enable" http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html settings enabled on the cluster

Comment: Hi -- no, no cluster.routing.* settings have been changed, so default values are active.

Comment: Is your cluster healthy? (`curl localhost:9200/_cat/health?v`)

Comment: Quite healthy; I get:  epoch      timestamp cluster    status node.total node.data shards pri relo init unassign 
1414094937 15:08:57  roadrunner green           4         4     38  19    0    0        0  In Marvel, I see all 4 nodes green, but only two of them hold primaries, while the other two only replicas. What gives?